# Logic App - The API connection eventhubs could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app , which uses Http trigger to receive azure monitor alerts and utilized Parse Json to parse it in json form.

Later it connects with event hub to send an information.
As soon as i establish a connection with Eventhub using EventHub connector automatically it creates APIConnection which has unique name e.g. eventhub-2 in my case.

Now i use the existing logic app ARM template to use a IAC to deploy it. I may work fine in same Resource Group in same subscription though while i run it in different resoure group , it throws me an ERROR API"The API connection 'eventhubs-2' could not be found.

because that API connection is limited to resource group only.
is it limitation of not using ARM template with other resource group of across subscription.

Kindly advise

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you need to create another connection in the resource group you want to deploy your logic app because the template of the logic app doesn't include the creation of the eventhub connection. So if we use the template to deploy the same resource group, it is ok. But if we want to deploy the logic app in the other resource group which doesn't have the connection, it will fail.

Comment: Yes, i know. it fails.but we wanted to use the ARM as ready for Infrastruture as a code..than there is no benefit of using it